# Does it follow from John 17:3 that knowing God alone cannot give eternal life? What then is the need for the adjectives "The only true"?

Tags: john, jesus, 1-john, son-of-god

Joh 17:3 NET2

> Now this is eternal life – that they know you, the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom you sent.

What is the meaning of the term "The only True God"?

When this is answered, will help us to understand what constitutes eternal life and its implications.

Eternal Life = God and Jesus Christ

This means God and another man or an angel do not equal eternal life.

Doesn't this make God and Jesus the Messiah in the same category?

As the scripture seems to mean that knowing God alone cannot give eternal life.

Comment: Who gave Jesus eternal life? Who does Jesus point to as the source of his life? Would Jesus state what is recorded in John 17:3 if it is not true? When did Jesus have eternal life? Would Jesus have eternal life if his Father/God did not resurrect him?

Comment: Why is the very Simple Understanding of Jesus? So complex to you?

Comment: Jesus - the Man beggoten by the Father .  Jesus- the eternal Word proceeding forth from the Father.   Do you understand the grammatical changes Jesus made to the Shema in John 17:3 and it's implications ?

Comment: I have answered your questions so far, but you have not answered mine.

Comment: Gods Spirit raised the man Jesus from the dead.  Jesus the Word of God is the Source of Life as is in the Father.  Jesus in time Pointed to the Father as his Logos.   Jesus the man was resurrected in time.

Comment: God raised Jesus from the dead. This Jesus did God raise up, whereof we all are witnesses Acts 2:32. The source of all life and creation is Jesus' God, not Jesus. Mark 13:19. The source of Eternal life, including that of Jesus is Jesus' God. Romans 6:23 Acts 2:32.

Comment: Scriptures also shows us how God Raised Jesus from the dead. Rom 8:11 BSB And if the Spirit of Him who raised Jesus from the dead is living in you, He who raised Christ Jesus from the dead will also give life to your mortal bodies through His Spirit, who lives in you.    Joh 10:18 BSB No one takes it from Me, but I lay it down of My own accord. I have authority to lay it down and authority to take it up again. This charge I have received from My Father.”

Comment: Also that God raised Jesus from the Dead dosen't also affect the Diety of Jesus.  I hope you know that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141115/discussion-between-faith-mendel-and-alex-balilo).

Comment: I like to put my comments out in the open. If what I believe is harmonious to the scriptures it should be able to stand scrutiny and reason. Thanks for the chat invitation.

Comment: I am only inviting you to chat because they site is warning me to about extended discussions.  If there are no issues then we can continue here.  You can answer my questions

Comment: I am warned of the same. You can post them as questions and I will try to answer them when I can.

Comment: I have answered your question in CH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever we conclude about John 17:3 must also agree with 1 John 5:11, 12 -

> And this is that testimony: God has given us eternal life, and this
> **life is in His Son**. Whoever has the Son has life; whoever does not have the Son of God does not have life.

Indeed, based on 1 John 5:11, 12, one might be justified in thinking that to know the Son alone is sufficient for eternal life.  Indeed, Jesus also said of Himself:

- John 11:25 - Jesus said to her, “I am the resurrection and the life. Whoever believes in Me will live, even though he dies.
- John 6:35-51 - Jesus said, "I am the bread of life"
- John 14:6 - Jesus said, "I am the way, the truth and the life".

Does this contradict John 17:3?  Definitely not!  Note that Jesus describes the Father in John 17:3 as:

- the one true God
- the source of eternal life

However, exactly the same description is given of Jesus as the source of eternal life (as shown above) AND Jesus is also described as the "true God" in 1 John 5:20

> And we know that the Son of God has come and has given us an
> understanding, that we may know Him who is true; and we are in Him who
> is true, in His Son Jesus Christ. This is the true God and eternal
> life.

[The antecedent of the last clause is the immediately previous noun, Jesus Christ.  See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/80129/who-is-the-true-god-and-eternal-life/80138#80138 ]

This is consistent with the repeated pattern of the NT in applying the same titles to the Father and to Jesus.

| The Father | Jesus Christ |
| --- | --- |
| John 17:3 - source of eternal life | 1 John 5:11, 12, John 11;25, 14:6, 6":35-51 - Jesus is the source of eternal life |
| Ps 23:1 - The LORD is my Shepherd. See also Isa 40:11, Eze 34:11 | John 10:11-16 - "I am the Good Shepherd. See also Heb 13:20, 1 peter 2:25, 5:4, Rev 7:17 |
| Ps 27:1 - The LORD is my Light". See also Micah 7:8 | John 8:12 - "I am the light of the world". See also John 1:9, 9:5, 1 John 1:5-7. |
| Isa 44:24, 45:18 - Creator alone | John 1:3, 10, Col 1:16, 17, Heb 1:2 - Jesus created all things |
| Isa 43:3, 11, 45:17, 21 - Savior of all, alone. | Matt 1:21; Acts 4:12; 2 Tim 1:10; Tit 1:4, 2:13, 3:6; 2 Pet 1:1, 11 - Jesus is the only Savior. |
| Isa 41:4, 44:6, 48:12 - "First and Last" | Rev 1:17, 18, 2:8, 22:13 - "First and Last" |
| Deut 10:17, Ps 136:3, 26 "LORD of Lords" | Rev 17:14, 19:16 "Lord of lords" |
| Deut 10:17, Josh 3:11, 13, Ps 97:5, Zech 4:14, 6:5, Mic 4:13, - "LORD of All" | Acts 10:36, Rom 10:12, Col 1:15 - "Lord of All" |
| Zech 4:10 (& Zech 3:9) - seven eyes of the LORD | Rev 5:6 (Lamb) "seven eyes" |

There are many more.

Comment: Great Answer. But I would like you to focus on my questions

Comment: @FaithMendel - have I not conclusively demonstrated that the NT teaches that Jesus is the Jehovah of the OT?

Comment: Ah! I see it now

Comment: @Dottard. Jesus life was caused by his Father/God John 6:57. He was created, John 3 :16, Revelation 3 :14. He ascribed creation to his God not to himself, Mark 13 /19 he is not the creator. If he is the only true God he will not pray to himself, John 17:3 nor would he say that he cannot of himself do nothing. If he is the only true God, he cannot die. His name is Jehoshua, not YHWH? He was born. There are many more.

Comment: @alex How is the begotten Son in John 3:16. The Created Son?    The reason why most persons do not answer your questions. Is because you haven't accepted the pure scriptures that identify the Word in. John 1. As Jesus

Comment: @FaithMendel. If what one understands is harmonious to the scriptures, it should be able to stand scrutiny.

Comment: What is your proof that the word in John 1. Is not Jesus.?  I have asked you before.  Who is Jesus?  Gleaning from your comments.  You seem to be in the wrong position about Jesus. And most of the books of the Bible are a polemic against your beliefs

Comment: @FaithMendel. Given the word in John 1 is Jesus, what are you trying to imply?

Comment: How do you translate the Theos in John 1c? Definitive, indefinitive, qualitative?

Comment: @FaithMendel - see  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/51178/is-john-11-meant-to-correct-the-second-temple-teaching-of-monotheism/51187#51187  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/76467/is-ho-theos-and-theos-consistently-translated-in-2-corinthians-44-and-john/76476#76476 https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/79242/how-to-understand-the-rendering-of-god-in-john-1-without-the-preceding-article-h/79248#79248

Comment: @Dottard. Thanks.  The question was for Alex.  I understand the Qualitative meaning of Theos in John 1c.    Your answers in the Links are just Perfect

Comment: You did not answer the question.

Comment: @JesusSaves - did you not even read what is written above? - Jesus and the Father are both the source of eternal life as described in the Bible.  However, your pre-suppositions presumably prevent from seeing the explicit testimony of Scripture - Jesus in the NT is described in the exactly the same terms as Jehovah of the OT.  I cannot put the dots any closer together!

Answer (score 4):

There is only one true God.  That is a theme throughout the Bible.  It's in the Ten Commandments--the worship of any other god breaks the first commandment.  It's in the Shema.  It's in Jesus' own teachings, John 17:3 being just one of the passages.

Jesus taught in simple terms that the Father was the One we should worship; that the Father was "the only true God"; and that the Father was both *his* God, and *our* God.  (See John 4:21-23; 17:3; 20:17.)

If the Father is "the only true God," as Jesus so plainly stated, then to have any other god is to break God's commandments.  Breaking the commandments is not the path to heaven or happiness.

With respect to "knowing God alone," I think it is safe to say that *we* cannot do anything to receive eternal life on our own.  We cannot even know God on our own.  Any knowledge we have of God has been given us through Jesus.

As the Bible says, no one has seen God at any time (John 1:18).  It also says we have never seen God's shape nor heard His voice.  Everything we can know about God is what Jesus has revealed.  This is why Jesus said that to know him was to know the Father.  He made it clear that he lived in obedience to the Father's will, and even the words which he uttered were those of the Father.

On a more serious note, it is true that no one will be lost for having believed a lie, but rather for having failed to believe the truth.  Each one needs to stop and consider the question: "Am I accepting all the truth God is giving me? or am I pridefully rejecting some truth in order to save face?  Am I rejecting some truth because I have cherished some opinion that is contrary to the truth?"

God is a God of truth.  We cannot truly worship God if our concept of God is wide of the truth.  If we have misunderstood God and His character, we cannot worship Him aright, and in place of eternal life, we may meet with shame, ignominy, and eternal death.

This is not a time to maintain foolish pride.  Accepting the truth humbly now will save us from a greater, and more tragic, humiliation later.  God's enemy desires to keep us from knowing the truth about who God is precisely because he knows how important this truth is to our salvation.  Will we follow the truth wherever it leads?  Will we accept the Bible as it reads, not wresting the scriptures to accommodate our fancies?

If so, there is no excuse for continuing to believe that there is some other "true God" beside the Father.  The Father, in Jesus' own words--too plainly spoken to be mistaken--is "the only true God."  Either we believe Jesus, or we believe a rationalization of our own choosing.  Failing to believe the truth, when we had opportunity to accept it, may cost us our salvation.

Comment: If the Shema testifies to the nature of God, why did Jesus fail to say the **one** true God or just the **one** God?

Comment: +1 "too plainly spoken to be mistaken" Clearly you've never met clever-sillies like St. Thomas Aquinas. ;)

Comment: @RevelationLad Jesus used the word "monos" which can be translated as only, single, or solitary.  If there is a "single" God, that is every bit as clear as saying "one" God.  In fact, I would submit that it is _more_ clear, because "one" can be misinterpreted to mean a "unity" of _several_...as many already seek to do.  There can be no such "unity" of multiple entities with the word "single" or "solitary."  It is very literally **only one.**

Comment: @Biblasia. Jesus would not have prayed and stated what is recorded in John 17:3 if he and his God are the only true God/s. If others claim Jesus' Father/God is not the only true God as Jesus stated, then they are equivocating to include their notion of their true God, which is not consistent with Jesus ' only true God. What is obvious is Jesus did not pray to himself or a false God. As Jesus said, If they don’t listen to Moses and the prophets, they will not be persuaded if someone rises from the dead.’ "

Comment: @Biblasia Can you admire the sun that provides sun-tan without co-admiring the sun-rays that provide this tan? Impossible to worship the Father without co-worshipping the Son who demands the same honor (John 5:23). You say, “we know God only through Jesus”, and through whom Jesus knows God? Without mediation? Then God can also, in principle, give us His knowledge also immediately but only chooses to do it through Jesus? No! God is ontologically unable either to communicate us His knowledge without His co-eternal Logos or even to create universe without the Logos (John 1:1-3).

Comment: Jesus speaking from his Hupotaso called the Father the True God Alone or Only.  That doesn't affect the Full deity of Jesus spoken about in many verses.

Comment: @FaithMendel Jesus is never said to have "full deity" in any verse.  However, because Jesus speaks the Father's words, and the Father is dwelling in him, he speaks like God.  See John 12:49; 14:10.

Comment: Hebrews was written to you also, A polemic to those who equate Jesus to Rankings as a Prophet.  Jesus speaks like God as God(qualitative) And yes Although because of the Humiliation of the Word in becoming Flesh (Phil 2) It still pleased the fullness of the Godhead to dwell in him bodily.

Comment: Are you referring to Hebrews 10:5?  Clearly, that "body" was not pre-existent, and it was not God.  Jesus' humanity was not God.  God did not die, because God is immortal and cannot die (see 1 Tim. 1:17; 6:16).  Nor was God tempted, because God cannot be tempted (see James 1:13).  To make Jesus' humanity equal God you will need something more than scripture, because scripture does not teach this.

Answer (score 2):

No, if you were able to magically just know the Father, you'd be good to go.

The whole point of the Gospel of John is that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, *who makes the Father known*. Jesus is the *way* to the Father. So you have to know Jesus *in order to know the Father*.

As the Gospel says early on (John 1:18),

> "No one has ever seen God"

So how can you 'see' (know) God (the Father)? Through Jesus, who makes the Father known.

**Q.** How does Jesus make the Father known?

**A.** Good question. The most obvious way is through Jesus' teachings. "I am a man who has heard the truth from God." (John 8:40) "I am the way, the truth, and the life." (John 14:6) neatly ties the ideas together. Jesus even has the title of 'the Word' (Revelation 19:13) because he speaks God's word, and in this sense of an image or representation 'is' God (as Jesus himself says at John 10:35, one can be called 'theos' - the Greek word for 'God' - if the word of God comes to him, and each judge was called 'theos', or similarly Moses was called the Hebrew equivalent to 'theos', 'elohim', at both Exodus 4:16 and 7:1 - most translations add 'as' or 'like' here but it is a translation gloss and not in the original).

The next obvious way Jesus makes the Father known is his actions, which can become a model for any Christian.

But it goes beyond this, because Jesus is now an ascended man at the right hand of the Father. In this capacity, He can send the Holy Spirit (John 16:7), which is God's presence, and so make the Father known in an intuitive, experiential sense. "However, when the Spirit of truth comes, He will guide you into all truth." (John 16:13)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141133/discussion-on-answer-by-one-god-the-father-does-it-follow-from-john-173-that-kn).

Answer (score 1):

We must understand there is a progressive revelation of the plan of salvation:

> <sup>38</sup> Whoever believes in me, as the Scripture has said, ‘Out of his heart will flow rivers of living water.’” <sup>39</sup> Now this he said about the Spirit, whom those who believed in him were to receive, for as yet the Spirit had not been given, because Jesus was not yet glorified. (John 7 ESV)

What Jesus said, was not fully understood until **after** He was glorified (crucified and resurrected).

It is possible to have a partial and therefore, incomplete knowledge of the plan:

> <sup>28</sup> And one of the scribes came up and heard them disputing with one another, and seeing that he answered them well, asked him, “Which commandment is the most important of all?” <sup>29</sup> Jesus answered, “The most important is, ‘Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, the Lord is **one, εἷς**. <sup>30</sup> And you shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind and with all your strength.’ <sup>31</sup> The second is this: ‘You shall love your neighbor as yourself.’ There is no other commandment greater than these.” <sup>32</sup> And the scribe said to him, “You are right, Teacher. You have truly said that he is one, and there is no other besides him. <sup>33</sup> And to love him with all the heart and with all the understanding and with all the strength, and to love one's neighbor as oneself, is much more than all whole burnt offerings and sacrifices.” <sup>34</sup> And when Jesus saw that he answered wisely, he said to him, **“You are not far from the kingdom of God.” And after that no one dared to ask him any more questions**. (Mark 12)

"Not far from" still means falling short. Unfortunately no one asked Jesus what was lacking in order to finally obtain the Kingdom of God. The Gospel of John "fills in the blank." One must be born again by believing in His name. But the question still remains, believe what about His name?

> <sup>9</sup> because, if you confess with your mouth that Jesus is Lord and believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you will be saved. <sup>10</sup> For with the heart one believes and is justified, and with the mouth one confesses and is saved. (Romans 10)

Only if one believes in the resurrection is one saved. The scribe in Mark's Gospel was not far from the Kingdom of God. What was lacking was a belief God would raise Jesus from the dead.

However, what was something that was yet to happen when the scribe was speaking to Jesus, happened, and is now in the past. So what does it mean **after** the resurrection to believe God raised Jesus from the dead?

> Who is to condemn? Christ Jesus is the one who died—more than that, who was raised—who is at the right hand of God, who indeed is interceding for us. (Romans 8:34)

Jesus was raised from the dead and is now at the right hand of God. We are saved only because from this position of authority, Jesus is interceding for us.

Jesus was not at the right hand of God when He was praying to the Father:

> And this is eternal life, that they know you, the only, μόνον, true God, and Jesus Christ whom you have sent. (John 17)

As is clear from Mark Jesus knew the Shema, but in opening His prayer He does not use one (εἷς) true God, or even more correctly one, εἷς God. Instead, Jesus abandons the Shema saying the Father is the μόνον true God. In addition, Jesus changes εἷς which means one to μόνον which means either  alone or only. At the time Jesus is praying, He is not at the right hand of God; the Son and the Father are temporarily separated, a condition which explains the Father the **alone** true God.

Contrary to the Shema, the adjectives μόνον ἀληθινὸν are necessary since  the Son is not in the Father's presence **at that point in time**. However, **after** resurrection, the Son is back at the right hand of God so when John writes His letter, μόνον is no longer necessary:

> And we know that the Son of God has come and has given us understanding, so that we may know him who is true; and we are in him who is true, in his Son Jesus Christ. He is the true God and eternal life. (1 John 5:20)

Comment: So Jesus reworked the Shema to include himself? The Father + Jesus is now the only true God?

Comment: Can't you see the Greek states so directly ?

Comment: @FaithMendel. What does the Greek states so directly?

Comment: In the Law it states 
Deu 6:4  άκουε Ισραήλ  κύριος ο θεός ημών  κύριος εις  εστί 

Jesus says...  Bracket emphasis.
Mar 12:29  Ἀπεκρίθη ὁ Ἰησοῦς “Ὅτι Πρώτη ἐστίν( ‘Ἄκουε, Ἰσραήλ, Κύριος ὁ Θεὸς ἡμῶν Κύριος εἷς ἐστιν, )

Comment: @FaithMendel. The Shema does not have Jesus name in it? Nor is he the one in the Shema.

Comment: I didn't say it has the name of Jesus in it.  Read revelation Lads Answer again to get exactly why I pointed that out

Comment: @AlexBalilo εἷς true God is not the same as μόνον true God. You must accept Jesus did not describe God as "one."

Comment: @FaithMendel Revelation Lad. Then who is referred to in the Shema. Why "must I accept  Jesus did not describe God as" one '?

Comment: @AlexBalilo The issue is the Shema and John 17:3 are two completely different ways to describe God. So pick one and explain the other and, more importantly, explain why in His final words, Jesus would give us something to replace the Shema. Something which John further modifies in this letter.

Comment: @RevelationLad. I asked it because your answer say "Jesus abandons the Shema".

Comment: @rev is this a binitarian answer? Where is the HS in this game of thrones? The imaginative idea that Jesus was missing does not explain why the HS was also missing - leaving the Father alone. Fascinating! Conjecture upon conjecture.

Comment: @steveowen If you read John 14-16 you will find the Holy Spirit, both when Jesus was speaking and after the crucifixion and resurrection.

Comment: @rev Maybe so, but it is not the one true God is it, this is the Father only. Just no one knows the son except the Father etc.

Answer (score 1):

This question shows a misunderstanding of the word "know" as used by Jesus in John 17:3. This misunderstanding and this question about it, gives the verse the appearance of saying something that it is not truly saying about who the true God is and who the source of eternal life is. Would Jesus say what he said if what he said is lacking and that "knowing God cannot give eternal life"?  Is there any record of anybody asking or correcting Jesus that knowing God "alone" cannot give eternal life?

they may know
γινώσκωσιν (ginōskōsin)
Verb - Present Subjunctive Active - 3rd Person Plural
Strong's 1097: A prolonged form of a primary verb; to 'know' in a great variety of applications and with many implications.

Know as defined above shows more than the OP's use of "knowing God alone". The kind of knowledge in John 17:3 is not the kind of knowledge that Adam and Eve had after eating the fruit of the tree in the midst of the garden. This knowledge made Adam and Eve behave according to their standards and placed their judgments above God instead of obeying God.

The needed knowledge is knowledge about God and His purposes. This kind of knowledge implies devotion to God and obedience to his Christ and this is implied in John 17:3. This is knowledge in a great variety of application and with many implications. We are however advised to be on guard against philosophies that are falsely called knowledge, 1Timothy 6:20.

1 Timothy 6:20 ASV

O Timothy, guard that which is committed unto thee, turning away from the profane babblings and oppositions of the knowledge which is falsely so called

OP asks What is the meaning of the Term "The only True God'?

Jesus said in his prayer to his Father/God And this is life eternal, that they should know thee the only true God, and him whom thou didst send, even Jesus Christ. What reason is there to believe that Jesus' God/Father is not the true God or that there is another one besides his Father/God? Would Jesus pray to his Father/God, the only true God, if his Father/God is not the only true God? How can Jesus be the faithful and true witness, (Revelation 3:14) if what he said is not true? What reasons are there to believe that he is the only true God whom he identifies as his Father? Jesus could not be the only true God as the Father is because that contradicts what he said in his prayer in John 17:3.

According to Jesus, his and his Father's testimonies equals 2 testimonies as John 8:17-18 shows, Jesus said that the testimony of two men is true I am he that beareth witness of myself and the Father that sent me beareth witness of me. Thus, Jesus cannot be the only true God as his God is and be counted as "one", the cardinal number 1, as John 8:17-18 show. The only true God is not a composition of multiple persons nor is the one (1) true God a compound unity of persons.

John 17:3 ASV

And this is life eternal, that they should know thee the only true God, and him whom thou didst send, even Jesus Christ

Revelation 3:14 ASV

And to the angel of the church in Laodicea write: These things saith the Amen, the faithful and true witness, the beginning of the creation of God:

John 8:17-18 ASV

Yea and in your law it is written, that the witness of two men is true I am he that beareth witness of myself, and the Father that sent me beareth witness of me.

Jesus also said in his prayer to his Father/God that the Father's word is truth John 17;17. So if Jesus words and the words of his God are truths, what reasons do we have in this case, to say knowing God alone cannot give eternal life? If our understanding of the word "know" is the same as Jesus Christ meant it, then that can give us eternal life just as Jesus said it in John 17:3. Philosophies that are falsely called knowledge leads to ideas that contradict inspired writings will not give us eternal life. Paul warned Timothy of this kind of knowledge, empty words of false teachers, who make a show of their learning and seek to influence the congregation. 1 Timothy 6:20

John 17:17 ASV

Sanctify them in the truth: thy word is truth.

Timothy 6:20 ASV

O Timothy, guard that which is committed unto thee, turning away from the profane babblings and oppositions of the knowledge which is falsely so called;

Eternal Life

The source of eternal life is Jesus' Father/God. Romans 6:23; John 17:3; 1 John 5:11

Romans 6:23 ASV

For the wages of sin is death, but the gift of God is eternal life in Christ Jesus our Lord

1 John 5:11 ASV

And the witness is this, that God gave unto us eternal life, and this life is in his Son

OP asks, As the scripture seems to mean that knowing God alone cannot Give Eternal Life?

The last part of the OP's question is a speculation. If the kind of knowing that Jesus use in John 17:3 is lacking, he would not have said what he said in John 17:3

In addition, the apostles never believed and taught that Jesus is their God nor their ancestors God as Acts 3:13 show.

Acts 3:13 ASV

The God of Abraham, and of Isaac, and of Jacob, the God of our fathers, hath glorified his Servant Jesus; whom ye delivered up, and denied before the face of Pilate, when he had determined to release him.

Comment: -1 for eisegesis of the Text.  And Assumptions.    The Word know used there is ginōskōsin.  My question comes from the use of the word Kai' which is mostly interpreted as a conjunction.  If it is a a conjunction. Then as other answers above have pointed, it means Eternal Life can't be gotten by Gisniskosin Theon alone!    It's very Clear.   I then asked for the implications of this...

Comment: @FaithMendel. Does it follow from John 17:3 that Knowing God alone cannot give Eternal Life? What then is the need for the adjectives "The only True"  What is the meaning of the Term "The only True God'

When this is answered, will help us to understand What constitutes Eternal Life and its Implications.

Eternal Life = God and Jesus Christ

This means, God and another man or an Angel does not equal Eternal Life.

Doesn't this make God and Jesus the Messiah in the same Category?

As the scripture seems to mean that knowing God alone cannot Give Eternal Life? That is your question.

Comment: Same as I Paraphrased above.  Maybe you should read again.

Comment: @FaithMendel. You can say that my answers to your questions are eisegesis. Does it make them so as you say they are.? I would let reason  and truth determine that. The God of the bible is a God of reason.

Comment: Yes eisegesis is reading into the text.  And that's what you are doing.  Making light commentaries that are not from the text. But placing them Into the text

Comment: @FaithMendel. What did I read into the text?

Comment: So if Jesus words and the words of his God are truths, what reasons do we have in this case, to say knowing God alone cannot give eternal life? If our understanding of the word "know" is the same as Jesus Christ meant it, then that can give us eternal life just as Jesus said it in John 17:3.  Jesus said in that same verse.  Eternal life is knowing the Father (and) Jesus the Messiah.

Comment: @FaithMendel. If the kind of knowing that Jesus used in John 17:3 is lacking, he would not have said what he said in John 17:3.

Comment: I can't comprehend what you intend to imply by the use of the words. Lacking.   I have said severely. That Jesus and all scriptures equates the knowledge of the Son as the Knowledge of the Father.  And the Knowledge of the Father as the knowledge of the Son.  Also the revelation is exclusive to the Persons in the Godhead

Comment: @FaithMendel. You already judged my answer. Who are the persons of the Godhead? How many are these persons of the Godhead?

Comment: The Father, The Word, The Spirit.  All one Being God.

Comment: @FaithMendel. Where in the bible does it plainly say  "The Father, The Word, The Spirit. All one being God"? I can't find a verse that says this.

Comment: Strawman logic. Off course it won't be written all together in the same verse exactly as I outlined it. But it doesn't mean it is not taught by the scriptures

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether the Lord Jesus Christ is necessary for God to enact His actions or if He can enact those actions even without the Lord Jesus Christ, but only chooses and decides to enact His deeds through the latter.

For instance, God can create man without sexual act of male and female, as He created Adam and then Eve, but chooses to bring new men to existence through the sexual act of man and woman (with exception of Christ who was conceived without male semen, but miraculously).

However not so with reference to the Lord Jesus Christ, for it is ontologically impossible for God to enact His deeds without His Logos/Son, who after His incarnation is also called Jesus Christ. Thus whenever God is mentioned in a worshiping context, there Jesus Christ is also mentioned as the one whom we simultaneously co-worship: “yet for us there is but one God, the Father, from whom all things came and for whom we live; and there is but one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom all things came and through whom we live” /1 Cor. 8:6/. We also read that all, without exclusion, promises of God were enacted in and through Christ: “For no matter how many promises God has made, they are “Yes” in Christ” /2 Cor. 1:20/. Thus it is not that God chooses not to make His promises “yes” without the Lord Jesus Christ, but God cannot make His promises “yes” without Christ.

Now, what is ont-ologically necessary for God is also a necessary and unavoidable aspect of God’s very ont-icity or reality, and as such is also God. Thus, impossible to have Father as God without having also the Son, Jesus Christ as God /cf. 1 John 2:23/. It is not out of choice that when having created the entire universe, God  did it
through the Logos/Son (John 1:1-3), but out of ontological necessity, and thus the Son is not a creature, but the co-Creator, and as such - uncreated, and as uncreated - God.

Comment: +1Up Voted for this sentence... Now, what is ont-ologically necessary for God is also an aspect of God’s ont-icity or reality, and as such is also God.

Comment: @FaithMendel Thanks for reading and estimating!

Comment: @Down-voter Hey, my anonymous future friend! Can you lay down your reasons for the down-vote? Just interested.

Comment: @Down-voter Nr.2 Please, my another anonymous future friend, read my message to your colleague, the first anonymous down-voter here abiove!

Answer (score -1):

SIMPLE ANSWERS

Joh 17:3 NET2 Now this is eternal life – that they know you, the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom you sent.

What is the meaning of the Term "The only True God'

ANSWER: As used by Jesus, considering the context where it was used " Jesus Prayer" it means the Father is the sole personal living God in glorious contrast equally with heathen polytheism, philosophic naturalism, and mystic pantheism.

This does not deflect the Deity of Jesus(The eternal word) but distinguishes True Religion from false ones.

When this is answered, will help us to understand What constitutes Eternal Life and its Implications.

Eternal Life = God and Jesus Christ

This means, God and another man or an Angel does not equal Eternal Life.

Doesn't this make God and Jesus the Messiah in the same Category?

Answer: Yes it Implies so, Thus Juxtaposition raises the divinity of Jesus as he equates knowing the Father and Him as the Source for Eternal Life.

As the scripture seems to mean that knowing God alone cannot Give Eternal Life?
Answer:
Yes Many other scriptures shows that the knowledge of the Father and the Son is Exclusive to them both (off course with the 3rd person in the Being God called the Spirit of God)

Mat 11:27 BLB  All things have been delivered to Me by My Father. And no one knows the Son, except the Father; nor does anyone know the Father, except the Son, and to whom the Son might choose to reveal Him.

Joh 1:18 BLB No one has ever yet seen God. The only begotten God, b the One being in the bosom of the Father, He has made Him known.

John 6:46 BLB Not that anyone has seen the Father, except the One being from God; He has seen the Father.

All this cannot escape the implication that the Son must be as eternal as the Father hence God(Qualitative)

Comment: -1 Saying _"GOD is the sole personal living God in glorious contrast equally with heathen polytheism,"_ is redundant (GOD = God?) and says nothing much at all, and to specify "heathen polytheism" leaves open some other kind of polytheism.  Trinitarianism is a form of polytheism: the belief in Three Gods (God the Father, God the Son, God the Spirit--all separate entities).  Your answer  is also difficult to follow, and would be more understandable with some grammatical fixes/clarifications.

Comment: Trinitarian beliefs should be separated from Tritheist  and modalism.   There is nothing redundant about the Phrase.  Remember that Jesus was Praying to the Father.  And then the previous verse says...Joh 17:2 BLB As You gave Him authority over all flesh, so that all whom You have given Him, He may give to them eternal life. ..   Jesus proceeds to explain the source of eternal life.  By the use of the word "Now this"    so here Jesus distinguishes True religion from all false and heathen ist concepts about Eternal Life.

Comment: @faith *This means, God and another man or an Angel does not equal Eternal Life.* This is not what the verse says, but your personal interpretation of its meaning. "that they know"... Jesus... John explained in his epistle that the true Jesus came in the flesh. If we know *this* (Biblical) Jesus, instead of the *hybrid God/man* Jesus. Heb 2:17 says he was made like us - fully human, another Adam. If you can seriously think that a God/man Jesus is made like us, you have picked the imposter Jesus and don't know Jesus as the verse requires. It's about *knowing* the true Jesus.

Comment: The verse implies it.  I didn't say that it "said it". However the Implication is Adequate.  As there is no where in the scriptures where the True Knowledge of God the Father is gotten apart from Jesus Christ. Which in turn is Eternal.   How can you not see that in the texts? Or in the whole of John.  Read with an Unbais eye.  Not everything should be read with your Unitarian Dogma